# Component that checks if objects of one java.lang.reflect.Type can be casted to another?

Tags: java, generics

Java exposes generic type information e.g. for field types at runtime through interface `java.lang.reflect.Type` and its subinterfaces (ParameterizedType, WildcardType).

Does anybody know where I can find a component that can determine if objects of one Type can be casted to another Type, e.g. if a `Set<Object>` can be casted to `Set` or a `Comparator<User>` can be casted to `Comparator<? extends Object>`?

The solution should work for type information represented by `java.lang.reflect.Type`, not only `Class`es, and it should take generics into consideration, i.e. a `List<Integer>` should not be castable to a `List<Object>`.

Regards,
Jochen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Guava's](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) [`TypeToken`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/reflect/TypeToken.html#isAssignableFrom%28java.lang.reflect.Type%29) is designed for exactly this problem, among others.  It's meant to be  a replacement for `Class` that's generics-aware.  (Disclosure: I contribute to Guava.)

Comment: After looking at both, I think I like Guava's approach a bit better. Purely subjective, of course.

Comment: You should decide on your own, so have a look at Guillaume's answer, too.

Answer (score 4):

JYou may have a look at [Apache Commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/):

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.7/org/apache/commons/lang3/reflect/TypeUtils.html

Comment: I want to point out that using TypeUtils.isAssignable(...) does not let you check for safe down casts. For instance a cast from Collection<Foo> to List<Foo> is perfectly safe, yet Collection<Foo> is not "assignable" to List<Foo>. The original question implies that isAssignable is sufficient, but the word "cast" is used throughout, so I thought it worth a mention.

Comment: I _think_ that you can cast from `A` to `B` if one of them is assignable to the other.

Comment: Let `A := List<Integer>` and  `B := Collection<? extends Number>`. `A` is assignable to `B`, yet a cast from `B` to a `A` would be unchecked and therefore unsafe.

Comment: @BenSchulz running `System.err.println(TypeUtils.isAssignable(Collection.class, List.class)); System.err.println(TypeUtils.isAssignable(List.class, Collection.class));` prints `false` `true`. I can safely cast a List to a Collection but not the other way around. I don't understand what the problem is with that.

Comment: @GuillaumePolet You may cast a value of type `Collection<X>` to `List<X>` and the cast either will fail (maybe it's a `HashSet<X>`) or it will succeed, because the value was a `List<X>`. All the cast really checks is that the value is a `List` (raw type), but if it is a `List` then there is no way that it is a `List<Y>`, with `Y != X` because any class can only implement one parameterization of any given interface (here `Collection`). That means the cast is safe (no heap pollution before the cast => no heap pollution afterwards).

Answer (score 0):

```
if (clazz.isAssignableFrom(otherClazz))
{
    return true; 
}
```

Comment: This only works for `Class` objects, not for `Type`, and it does not take generics into consideration.